# Nested constant size loop time complexity O(n) or O(n^2)?

Tags: nested, time-complexity, big-o

I know if I have a nested loop depending on N elements, the time complexity for it would be O(N^2).

In the case I have a constant size loop, nested in a N loop, like this:

```
while (i < N)
    while (j < 1000){
       // code //
       j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

what would be the time complexity here? Its not O(N^2) but I dont know if its O(N) or something in between. It doesnt seem linear to me.
T

Answer (score 2):

The constant size loop takes constant time (`O(1)`), so the entire loop indeed has linear time complexity, `O(N)`.